# How to use doc.location.href.search within an array

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a basic Firefox plugin with which I want to block certain domain names and let them redirect to another external webpage.

How can I let 'doc.location.href.search' search within the VAR 'blockedSites' ?
(And if anyone knows how to fix the problem where Firefox loads the correct redirect-website, but in fullscreen-mode removing all tabs, would be welcome aswell)

This is the code so far:

```
    onPageLoad: function (aEvent) {
    var doc = aEvent.originalTarget;
    var blockedSites=["domain1.com","domain2.net","domain3.org"];
    if (doc.location.href.search("blockedSites") > -1)
{
    window.location = "http://redirect-to-this.com"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) instead of `search`:

```
if (blockedSites.indexOf(doc.location.href) >= 0)
```

`indexOf` will return the position the string in the array, so it must be 0 or greater to be an blocked site.